# Stops at for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

When I am running my code, it always stops at the for loop and skips it.

```
public void assignCell()
{
    Prisoner prisoner = prisoners.get(id-1);
    for(Cell cell : cells)
    if(cell.isAvailable())
    {
        cell.allocate(prisoner);
        String bunk = null;
        if(cell.isEven())
        {
            bunk = "top bunk of cell";
        }
        else
        {
            bunk = "only bunk of cell";
        }
        System.out.println("\t\t" + prisoner.nameToString() + " is in the " + bunk + cell.toString());
    }

}
```

How can I fix this so it goes through?

Comment: Are there any `Cell` instances in the `cells` collection? Are you getting any exceptions, or is it just not doing what you expect?

Comment: Skeet is on to something with his answer about the missing break. I'm going to guess that your loop runs through and assigns all of the cells to one prisoner because of a missing break statement. There then will be no more available cells for the next time that you call the assignCell method making it appear to skip the loop.

Answer (score 7):

That would suggest that `cells` is empty. If it's not, we're just guessing - please post a *complete* program.

However, I would *strongly* urge you to add braces around your `if` statement<sup>1</sup>:

```
public void assignCell()
{
    Prisoner prisoner = prisoners.get(id-1);
    for(Cell cell : cells)
    {
        if(cell.isAvailable())
        {
            cell.allocate(prisoner);
            String bunk = null;
            if(cell.isEven())
            {
                bunk = "top bunk of cell";
            }
            else
            {
                bunk = "only bunk of cell";
            }
            System.out.println("\t\t" + prisoner.nameToString() 
                               + " is in the " + bunk + cell);
        }
    }
}
```

In fact, I'd then try to reduce the nesting, and use the conditional operator too:

```
public void assignCell()
{
    Prisoner prisoner = prisoners.get(id-1);
    for(Cell cell : cells)
    {
        if(!cell.isAvailable())
        {
            continue;
        }
        cell.allocate(prisoner);
        String bunk = cell.isEven() ? "top bunk of cell" : "bottom bunk of cell";
        System.out.println("\t\t" + prisoner.nameToString() 
                           + " is in the " + bunk + cell);

    }
}
```

Oh, and you *probably* want a `return` or `break` statement there, otherwise a single prisoner will be assigned to *all* the available cells. Indeed, that may be happening with your first prisoner: check the output of the program very carefully!

---

<sup>1</sup> Another alternative is just to indent the `if` statement - but give *some* indication that you really did mean the `if` statement to be in the loop. Personally I find it helpful always to use braces, as then you can't accidentally add another statement after the first one which *looks* like it would be part of the loop, but isn't. Readability is king, IMO.

Comment: Why would one *strongly* urge anyone else to adhere to his style?

Comment: I believe you mean 'for' statement.

Comment: @hacker: It's not really an issue of style when the vast majority of competent programmers, in addition to nearly every book on the subject, say that you should use braces in this situation.

Comment: @hacker: Because it will lead to fewer bugs. It's as simple as that. The current code is horrible - it uses neither braces *nor* indentation to indicate that the `if` statement is within the `for` loop. Just indenting would be another option, but in my experience it's simpler to stick to a rule of "always use braces" and avoid worrying about it when you change from a single-statement loop to a multiple-statement loop, etc.

Comment: I agree with braces around the "for". With that however, the nesting is a bit deep so I would reverse the logic of the 1st if to reduce the nesting by one level, e.g. if(!cell.isAvailable()) continue;

Comment: @hacker: if the OP had used variable names of `l1` and `ll` instead of `prisoner` and `cell`, would you have objected to me strongly recommending that sensible names should be used?

Comment: @SingleShot: You mean like I did in the second listing? :)

Comment: Jon, I would. No matter what Welbog says it *is* a matter of style and the majority of incompetent programmers producing majority of bugs do embrace each and every statement. It will *not* lead to fewer bugs. Actually, even indentation will not help. But what struck me as out-of-place was not the idea of braces, but urging to follow your example. jjnguy above also said that "he'd enclose loop in braces". And I would, to tell you the truth ;-)

Comment: @hacker: I have absolutely no qualms about urging and strongly encouraging people to follow what I see as best practices. It absolutely *does* lead to fewer bugs, btw - I have seen bugs of scoping which would simply not have happened with braces in the right place. Whether you call it style or best practices, I see nothing wrong with encouraging people to follow a path which is likely to lead to code which is more readable and thus easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: To give other examples: if someone presented you with code which was formatted into a single line several thousand columns long, are you seriously saying you *wouldn't* urge them to format it? I think it is our *duty* to provide advice where we see others falling into habits which we believe will lead to code which is hard to maintain. Just because you can follow bracing rules and still end up with bad code doesn't mean the bracing rules aren't at least a good *start*.

Comment: readability outside of corporate environment is also subjective. I, for instance, find the code taking up less vertical space much more readable and find wasting extra line on each curly brace very disturbing (I don't mean saving on the loop, but general habit of dedicating extra line to the brace). And you know what - I've seen this "best practice" lead to *a lot* of bugs concerning the general flow and understanding of one's own program (not to mention my own eyes being hurt). I think that the best practice is letting people write the code they maintain the best.

Comment: Well, if someone presented the one-liner to me, I'd prefer to stay away from this code and let this someone maintain it ;-) You're right about the duty - it makes sense. It's just that I had this feeling that you're too eager to perform it ;-) In comparison with the other speaker(s) who expressed the same attritude towards braces, but didn't trigger my rebellious self ;-)

Comment: @hacker: If I genuinely thought that giving *no* visual indication that the `if` statement was meant to be in the loop was *actually* the code style that the OP would maintain the best, I wouldn't have said anything. I don't for one minute believe that's the case though. Even outside the corporate environment, I usually write code assuming that someone other than myself will want to read it... and I really don't like dense code with very few spaces. I will accommodate opening braces to end-of-line or new-line according to project style, but there has to be *some* indication of desired nesting.

Comment: I think we'll have to agree to differ - but if the same situation came up again, I'd act exactly the same way. I have no reservations about encouraging people to write readable code. They don't have to take my advice, but I'm certainly going to offer it.

Comment: What I meant to say is that there's really-really no universal readability. And, anyway, I'm actually sorry I jumped in. It was something in the wording. Besides, there's an answer down there that *only* suggests embracing the `for` content. Without even touching the matter. That's the extreme the everyday sight of which made me attack you ;-)

Comment: I would throw Code Complete 2 at anyone that wrote code like this for a project that I was working on.

Comment: hoffmandirt, I wouldn't work on a project with anyone throwing anything heavier than exception.

Comment: @hacker: While there is no *absolute* universal readability, there are certain things which pretty much *everyone* will agree on.

Comment: @hacker, exceptions *are* heavy

Comment: Jon, I'd agree with you on braces. But I often find myself in the situation where I belong to minority. And it often takes considerable effort (and waste thereof) to prove my worthiness and establish my right to have an opinion. And I've seen many *pretty much everyones* being forced out of their habits just for the sake of majority. But I'd rather stop here before someone invokes Godwin's Law ;-)

Comment: bill weaver, but there's a catch block-ing the way.

Comment: So, assuming one downvote is from hacker: would anyone like to explain the other one?

Comment: I revoke my downvote. I actually was about to assure you it's not mine, when I found looked up to see it is.

Comment: @hacker: Thanks, that's appreciated (although I do take your point; I would personally say that for matters of readability, when I'm in the minority on a team, I'll bow to the wishes of the majority). However, there's still another downvote - that's what I'm confused about. I can't see anything technically *wrong* with my answer, and if there *is* something wrong with it, I'd really like to know about it...

Comment: But since my comment was upvoted, I think the other one is triggered by similar sentiments.

Comment: The problem with bowing to majority is that majority often thinks that code readability is a substitute for ability to read, which it is not.

Comment: @hacker: I guess it declares who you work with. Everyone I work with is quite capable of reading - but we debate the most readable form for the majority, and then stick to it consistently.

Comment: Heh, Jon, I worked with different people and find it best to let everyone figure out what's best for them and be tolerant to things that are best for others. This technique implies sharing your idea of best practices ("I would use braces here"), letting others exercise their ideas ("but if you wouldn't - don't"), letting them share their ideas ("look, by saving vertical space I get better grasp on the big picture) and letting them learn from their mistake ("what did I tell you - you would never screw up here if not your stubborn aversion to braces!").

Answer (score 7):

Even though the code looks correct, I would enclose the loop in braces.  It makes it much easier to read.

Besides that, I would check to make sure that `cells` has items in it.

Answer (score 4):

I'll mention this since no one else has: you should learn how to use the debugger that is bundled with your IDE. It can tell you if your cells array is empty. If you're using Eclipse, there are great debugging tutorial videos available here: http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/debugger.html

Comment: Good point. A debugger would quickly show you whether the list is empty or there is a missing break statement.

Comment: amen.  These sorts of questions are things that a debugger would address in less than 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your collection of cells isn't empty ? I would:

1. print the number of cells prior to looping (cells.size() if it's a collection, cells.length if it's an array)
2. print some cell info for *each* iteration, before you make any checks (clue: override toString() on the cell object and display availability etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `cell.isAvailable()` returns `true` when it is supposed to. The only way the loop could appear to be "skipped" is if the collection `cells` is empty or none of the cells are "available."

Answer (score -1):

For a start I would put the contents of the for loop into {}